# FFMPEG conversion error from MKV to MP4 using libfdk_aac codec

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, mkv, video-codecs, acc

The purpose of doing this is because my "Smart" samsung TV doesn't play MKV files.

[This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/472420/handbrake-settings-to-convert-mkv-to-mp4-while-retaining-the-original-quality) mentions that there is no need for video conversion, just changing the container might suffice. After reading multiple threads on how to change the container of MKV to MP4, I downloaded and compiled the FFMPEG with libfdk_aac support from [here](http://taer-naguur.blogspot.ca/2013/10/ffmpeg-autobuild-tool-x64.html). I tried converting a sample MKV file using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\VideoTest\Sample1.mkv" -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 384k "C:\VideoTest\Sample2.mp4"
```

but getting the following errors (copied from command prompt):

```
[hevc @ 0000000000308ae0] Could not find ref with POC 113
[hevc @ 0000000000308ae0] Could not find ref with POC 111
[hevc @ 0000000000308ae0] Could not find ref with POC 109
[hevc @ 0000000000308ae0] Could not find ref with POC 107
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'C:\VideoTest\Sample-1.mk
v':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1
    creation_time   : 2014-07-16 08:54:02
  Duration: 00:00:58.68, start: 0.042000, bitrate: 3520 kb/s
    Chapter #0.0: start 0.000000, end 58.717000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 4
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1920x816, SAR 1:1 DAR 40:17, 2
4 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on
 Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit buil
t on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2014-07-16 08:54:02
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2014-07-16 08:54:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      BPS             : 2733260
      BPS-eng         : 2733260
      DURATION        : 00:00:58.667000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:58.667000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 1408
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 1408
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 20044023
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 20044023
    Stream #0:1: Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 768 kb/s (default)

    Metadata:
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on
 Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit buil
t on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2014-07-16 08:54:02
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2014-07-16 08:54:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      BPS             : 767986
      BPS-eng         : 767986
      DURATION        : 00:00:58.625000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:58.625000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 5496
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 5496
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 5627904
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 5627904
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle, 1920x1080 (default)
    Metadata:
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on
 Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit buil
t on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2014-07-16 08:54:02
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2014-07-16 08:54:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      BPS             : 17485
      BPS-eng         : 17485
      DURATION        : 00:00:56.750000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:56.750000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 40
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 40
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 124036
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 124036
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\VideoTest\Sample.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.1.100
    Chapter #0.0: start 0.000000, end 58.675000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 4
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc ([35][0][0][0] / 0x0023), yuv420p, 1920x816 [SAR 1:
1 DAR 40:17], q=2-31, 24 fps, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on
 Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit buil
t on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2014-07-16 08:54:02
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2014-07-16 08:54:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      BPS             : 2733260
      BPS-eng         : 2733260
      DURATION        : 00:00:58.667000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:58.667000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 1408
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 1408
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 20044023
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 20044023
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, 5.1
, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on
 Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit buil
t on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2014-07-16 08:54:02
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2014-07-16 08:54:02
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      BPS             : 767986
      BPS-eng         : 767986
      DURATION        : 00:00:58.625000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:58.625000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 5496
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 5496
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 5627904
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 5627904
      encoder         : Lavc56.0.101 libfdk_aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (dts (dca) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0000000003be0500] Invalid DTS: 656 PTS: -672 in output stream 0:0
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
[libfdk_aac @ 00000000042fa640] Trying to remove 1024 samples, but the queue is
empty
[mp4 @ 0000000003be0500] Encoder did not produce proper pts, making some up.
[libfdk_aac @ 00000000042fa640] Trying to remove 1024 samples, but the queue is
empty
frame=    2 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      96kB time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=18415.0kbit
s/s
video:95kB audio:1kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing ov
erhead: 0.570364%
Conversion failed!
```

Also tried using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

But this screws up the video quality and I start seeing some bad pixelated patches during the playback.

Any help would be appreciated.

Just an FYI: I got this far by reading blogs and posts. I have 0 knowledge about video conversion.

Comment: Your second command `ffmpeg -i input.wav ...` has no video track input. So it can't screw up the video quality.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't play the video after your first command, then (evidently) your TV can't deal with the originally encoded video stream.  So - give a shot at re-encoding with another codec.  This will produce a high quality re-encoded version (it will take a while to re-encode):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -qscale 1 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 384k output.mp4
```